# Download Maven2 dependency from non-standard layout repository

Tags: maven-2, repository, hudson

I need to download a file from a non-standard layout repository.

The standard repository layout is `groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.<packaging>` however, I need to download the following file:

```
http://hudson.myserver.com:10000/repo/ocp-services/schemas/trunk/201/archive/schemas/dist/schemas.jar
```

where ocp-services is effectively the groupId, schemas is the artifactId and 201 is the version.

How would I add a dependency to this file and get it downloaded into my project and local repository?

This is a Hudson file repository if this is of any help, but it is a third parties so difficult to get them to change any location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to register a custom [`ArtifactRepositoryLayout`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.1.0/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/layout/ArtifactRepositoryLayout.html) implementation and to declare a repository using this custom layout. I've never done that but it should be possible, check this [blog post](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-register-a-custom-maven-repository-layout/).

A second option would be to configure Maven to go through some kind of custom proxy (e.g. a Servlet) and to rewrite the URL on the fly for this particular dependency.

In both cases, I'm afraid Maven will complain about missing metadata ("*A dependency in Maven isn't just a JAR file*", see [3.5.5. Maven's Dependency Management](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project-sect-dep-management.html)) because the hudson file repository is just **not** a Maven repository. Maybe this can be handled programmatically though. But as I said, I've never done this.

A third option would be to ask the project building the JAR you need to `deploy` it (in the maven sense). That would be of course the best solution.

A last one option would be to just download this JAR and to [install it](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) manually in your local repository. If this is an option, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to your pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ocp-services</groupId>
                <artifactId>schemas</artifactId>
                <version>201</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

or if that don't work as Pascal says install it manually